# How can I update multiple XML fields with MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Table Name  : TBL_CLIENTS
Table Field : XMLDATA

```
<REPORT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DESCRIPTION="TestClient" FILENUM="1234">
  <!--<REPORT DESCRIPTION="TestClient" FILENUM="1234">-->
  <TRACKING>
    <FIRSTNAME>Bobby</FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNAME>Butcher</LASTNAME>
  </TRACKING>
</REPORT>
```

I want to change both the FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME. Is there anyway I can do it in a single query? The only way I can figure it out is using two queries.

```
UPDATE TBL_CLIENTS
SET [XMLDATA].modify('replace value of (/REPORT/TRACKING/FIRSTNAME/text())  [1] with ("Franny")')
WHERE ORDERID = 5
```

and

```
UPDATE TBL_CLIENTS
SET [XMLDATA].modify('replace value of (/REPORT/TRACKING/LASTNAME/text())[1]  with ("Farmer")')
WHERE ORDERID = 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible - per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx), replace has to work on a single instance of an XML node - but you could avoid doing two `UPDATE`s on the table this way:

```
DECLARE @doc xml = '<REPORT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DESCRIPTION="TestClient" FILENUM="1234">
  <!--<REPORT DESCRIPTION="TestClient" FILENUM="1234">-->
  <TRACKING>
    <FIRSTNAME>Bobby</FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNAME>Butcher</LASTNAME>
  </TRACKING>
</REPORT>';

DECLARE @t table (xmldata xml);

insert @t (xmldata) values (@doc);

-- grab the XML data from the table for manipulation...
DECLARE @xmlData xml;
SELECT @xmlData = xmldata FROM @t;

set @xmlData.modify('replace value of (/REPORT/TRACKING/FIRSTNAME/text())  [1] with ("Franny")')                   
set @xmlData.modify('replace value of (/REPORT/TRACKING/LASTNAME/text())   [1] with ("Farmer")')

-- now we only need to do one update on the table itself.
UPDATE @t 
SET [XMLDATA] = @xmlData

SELECT * FROM @t;
```

I know this isn't exactly what you were asking for, but it should result in less locking time and better performance on the table - if that's something you're aiming for.